How can I link Product Backlog Items to Releases in Azure DevOps?
I'm working on a project in Azure DevOps and want to create a link between Product Backlog Items (PBIs) and releases. Ideally, I'd like to have a clear view of which PBIs are associated with each release so that I can track progress and see what’s going out in each deployment.
Any advice on the best practices for associating PBIs with releases would be appreciated!
I’ve tried looking into linking work items manually, but I’m not sure if this is the most efficient method or if there’s a better way to set it up. Specifically, I’d like to know:
Are there

any native features in Azure DevOps that allow for linking PBIs with release versions?
Can I automate this process, or do I need to manually link each PBI to the corresponding release?
Is there a way to visualize this linkage, perhaps within Azure Boards or another tool in the suite?


Have you tried the method to link work items to releases shared in the answer below? Does it work for you? @MowalimKalim

For existing releases, there is not method to link work items to them.
To link work items to releases, you can do with the following steps:

Link work item to commit.

When push a new commit, you can link work item like as below.


For existing commit, you can open the work item to link the commit like as below.




Link work item to build.

For existing build, you can open the work item to link the build like as below.


To automatically link new builds, you can set the build pipeline like as below. Enable the option "Automatically link new work in this build" (Classic build pipeline), or "Automatically link work items included in this run" (YAML pipeline).




Link work item to release. Enable the options "Report deployment status to Work" and "Report deployment status to Boards" on the release pipeline.



After above configuration, when you run a new build then then a release based on the commit which has linked with a work item, the release will be automatically link to the same work item.


